# Platform Independent Mobile Applications

Tags: iphone, android, ios, mobile, cross-platform

How far can we think of Platform Independent Mobile Applications ? The idea behind this question was - To use less efforts for building the same application for different platforms like Android , iOS , Symbian.

I had looked on some of the tools and got one [Open Plug](http://developer.openplug.com/). Will explore ASAP. What are your ideas on it ?

**EDIT :**
I then started exploring [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). I found it good enough to build the apps using HTML,CSS,JS, we can include JQueryMobile and Sencha Touch as well.

Comment: I guess this should be a community wiki. Although, there are more. I can think of `Appcelarator` and `Adobe AIR`

Comment: @Sheikh - Thanks for response. Please elaborate a bit ..

Comment: In `Appcelarator`, you code using its API and using JavaScript. it then generates builds for iPhone as well as Android devices, out of your same JavaScript code. as in `Adobe AIR`, you use their API and perhaps ActionScript, to code your app for the AIR platform, and wherever the AIR platform is implemented, your app will work. haven't seen any implementation of AIR yet.

Comment: Aren't they called "Platform Agnostic"?

Comment: Thanks Sheikh for the quick response , I was thinking to have one Tool for this.

Comment: Aurum Aquila - Sorry but didn't get you :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com) would be a good choice for non-game applications, it uses native UI elements as opposed to running apps in the mobile browser, lets you code in JavaScript and deploy to Droid, iPhone, iPad and soon Blackberry from one project.

For games I'd take a look at [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com). This lets you develop for Droid and iPhone in Lua which is even easier than JavaScript. They recently released a beta Windows SDK (it was previously Mac-only). This is a great SDK but lacks in controls that you would need for non-game applications.

Comment: Thanks Alan , I'll try Appcelerator :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting enterprise apps, you should consider Oracle's mobile enterprise application platform.

It's made up of 3 products: ADF Mobile, Berkeley DB, and (Lite) Mobile Server. More information here:

http://bit.ly/hxrYLQ

Good luck with your project,

Eric, Oracle PM

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Enterprise Mobility Forum http://theemf.org/groups/enterprise-mobility-management/forum/topic/meap-vendor-comparison/
Executive summary: no clear answer yet, lots of tradeoffs- both business and technical.

Comment: Thanks Mike but I don't think this is what I am looking for. .