# Phonegap and iPhone apps

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to build an iPhone app, but I only know PHP, JavaScript, CSS and HTML. I heard that I can use Phonegap to build the app in javascript and it converts the JavaScript to Objective-C. Is that true? The phone gap documentation was hard to understand. What other solutions do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Phonegap (nowadays known as [Apache Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/)) enables you to bundle web pages/applications as native phone apps. It also provides you with some JavaScript bindings to native phone APIs that you otherwise wouldn't be able to access (=with a plain webpage). These bindings include (just to name a few) [Accelerometer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer), [Camera](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) and [Compass](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_compass_compass.md.html#Compass). That's pretty much all it does - you still have to figure out how to write your application with JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

Try out how it works by checking out ["Getting Started with iOS"](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS).

Answer (score 0):

If you know all these languages you mentioned that is well enough for developing an iOS App(as well as you can develop the same apps in Android).

I would suggest you to go for [PhoneGap(Cordova)](http://phonegap.com/) framework to develop these apps. Using this framework you'll have to use HTML/HTML5, JavaScript, CSS, PHP and get the iOS App running on your device. Here to [StartWith](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_index.md.html) and then check out [APIDocs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/index.html). You will always get a lot of tutorials on google itself.

You can also refer [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077566/platform-independent-mobile-applications) for gathering some knowledge about other frameworks available in market.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Phonegap, but you can't use PHP with Phonegap apps directly... There are a few hacks around this though.

Although Phonegap is supposed to be "one codebase, distribute everywhere", if you want a really great looking app you'll have to spend a liitle time adjusting the UX for every platform or device. The thing I really like about Phonegap is that you can open up a HTML page locally on your browser and move thing around in firebug, making the process faster.